# jquery show / hide div on click even in a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, slideshow, show-hide

Is it possible to combine a slideshow and show / hide div functionality?

My html structure is below, and basically, I'm trying to get the tabs > a links to open up the div with the corresponding class if a user clicks on it.  If a user doesn't click on it, it should still just cycle through each image. So, if the images are rotating, and I click on `<a class="t2">` then  would open.  The thing is, it's unknown how many divs / tabs there will be, but they'll always be named t{n}.

```
<div id="tab-content">
   <div class="t1">content</div>
   <div class="t2">lorem ipsum</div>
   <div class="t3">knock knock</div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
   <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
         <li class="t1"><a class="t1" href="#">tab 1</a></li>
         <li class="t2"><a class="t2" href="#">tab 2</a></li>
         <li class="t3"><a class="t3" href="#">tab 3</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[update]***
I thought you only had an issue with the opening of the divs when you click the links..

For a complete slideshow that allows manual override from links have a look at [the cycle plugin for jquery](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) and in particular this demo ['updateActivePagerLink' Demo](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pager7.html)

***[Original answer]***

The following will add the functionality you want to all `a` elements inside the `#tabs` div
The functionality will be to show the element (inside `#tab-content`) with the same class as the `a` element that was clicked..

```
$('#tabs a').click( function() {
   $('#tabcontent .' + $(this).attr('class') ).show();
} );
```

Comment: That doesn't actually do what I need it to do.  It doesn't cycle through the images automatically, and it doesn't hide the content that doesn't have the same class...  Am I missing something?

Comment: oh .. thought you had a problem with the part of opening the div with the same class as the link ...  updated answer to point to a plugin that does what you want..